# Vba sap scripting if no icon found

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I'm new to vba and sap gui scripting, could someone point me into the right direction please?

I think I have a problem with the error handling statement maybe. it supposed to put the icon value(Green per example) in column C if there is any and to leave column C empty and put "No icon " on column B and then go to the next cell and check again if there is an icon or now.

I have a list of element in excel (Column A) that I want to check in sap and instead of checking one by one manually I'm working on a macro to check all the items on excel and returns the value of the icon (if green in sap, it should return the icon value and put it on column "C") if it doesn't find the icon it should put the value : no icon found on column "B".

I tried to put on error resume next but the problem is that it only work once and then it start puting the same value in column C and B regardless if there is a green icon or not.

if I don't put in error handling method, once there is no icon, vba shows that the problem is on but when I do the following it works properly (puts "no icon" )and end exit the macro:

```
'=====================Column A contains the Numbers I want to check on sap

on error goto msg

For Each rng In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Elements= Cells(Elem.Row, "A").Value
If Elem.Value Like "?56*" 

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPDV70ATC_NAST3").Columns.elementAt(0).Width = 4
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPDV70ATC_NAST3/lblDV70A-STATUSICON[0,1]").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPDV70ATC_NAST3/lblDV70A-STATUSICON[0,1]").caretPosition = 0
    Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPDV70ATC_NAST3/lblDV70A-STATUSICON[0,1]").IconName


Cells(rng.Row, "C") = value

End If
Next

msg:

cells(rng.row, "D").value = "No icon"
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.
Regads

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following.

for example:

'=====================Column A contains the Numbers I want to check on sap

```
'on error goto msg

For Each rng In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Elements= Cells(Elem.Row, "A").Value
If Elem.Value Like "?56*" 

on error resume next
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPDV70ATC_NAST3").Columns.elementAt(0).Width = 4
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPDV70ATC_NAST3/lblDV70A-STATUSICON[0,1]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPDV70ATC_NAST3/lblDV70A-STATUSICON[0,1]").caretPosition = 0
Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPDV70ATC_NAST3/lblDV70A-STATUSICON[0,1]").IconName

if err.number = 0 then
   Cells(rng.Row, "C") = Value
else
   Cells(rng.row, "D").value = "No icon"
end if
err.clear
on error goto 0
End If
Next

'msg:

'cells(rng.row, "D").value = "No icon"
End Sub
```

Regards, ScriptMan